# Needing clarification on Lifejacket and Lifeboat

Tags: support, bug, badges, lifejacket-lifeboat-badges

The description for these state

> Answer score of 5 or more to a question score of -2 or less that goes on to receive a score of 2 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Does that mean the overall score of the question is negative two, or that if the question gains two negative votes?

According to the way the blogpost sounds, it should be the first one, a question has an overall score that is negative, you answer positively, then boom award.  However, I've gotten this twice for two questions that have an overall high positive score (+11/-2 was the vote score on one).

Am I misunderstanding how these badges work, or is there a minor bug with this award?

Comment: Timing matters here. Was the post at -2 when the answer came in?

Comment: @TimPost is there a way to check the vote history of a question?

Comment: You could check the reputation of the OP.

Comment: @CBredlow you can see votes' timeline in the questionis timeline (URL `*.Stackexchange.com/id/timeline`), provided it wasn't on the same day, IIRC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does that mean the overall score of the question is minus two, or that the question gains two negative votes?

The former. Post score always refers to the number between the up- and downvote buttons, which is also shown on the question list and search results.

> However, I've gotten this twice for two questions that have an overall high positive score (+11/-2 was the vote score on one).

That could certainly happen when the first two votes were downvotes. Actually, it's [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/110143/44520) you were thinking of. It is currently scoring +11/-4, and you can check the OP's [reputation tab](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57047/5ht3f4n?tab=reputation) to see that the first *four* votes were downvotes:

[image]

Comment: Okay, and I guess you can't really take away badges over time.  I'll accept this since it explained what these badges really mean.

Comment: [The introductory blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/) post spells it out: for Lifejacket, “A user posted an answer to a question with a score of <= -2 at the time”, for Lifeboat, “A user posted an answer to a question with a score of <= -3 at the time”.